# Validation error for <h5> tag

Tags: html, css

When I try to validate my page, an error comes up regarding the  tag on the following HTML line:

```css
#footer {
    background-color: #000;
   color: turquoise;
   text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h5 class id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
```

The extra CSS code is because I have two images on my homepage and this was the solution so that the "footer" remains centered on the bottom of the page and below the images.

So if the  tag is not valid as I have it, how can I do it so it validates?

Comment: Remove  `class` so it just `<h5 id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>`

Comment: I doubt that the validator did just say "meh" and not give you an actual error message - so what was it, and what part of it was unclear ...?

Comment: The exact message was: Stray start tag h5.  From line 43, column 1; to line 43, column 22 </body>↩↩↩<h5 class id="footer">&copy;  My bad for not including the exact message.  I thought I included enough info without it,

Comment: @some Just tried that, same error message

Comment: I came here for help because I was not understanding what I was doing wrong.  Berating someone, especially when you have far more knowledge and a 67K+ reputation seems just way wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you've made multiple mistakes.

First of all, your class attribute is wrong.

```
<h5 class id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
```

Should become:

```
<h5 id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
```

Normally I would not recommend w3schools, but I think it would work out great for you here: https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_class.asp

Secondly, it seems like you have put your footer tag outside of your body.

Everything you want to show on your website, should be *inside* your `<body></body>`

Fix these two errors and you should be fine. Good luck!

Comment: You were 100% correct.  The problem was two-fold.  It was mentioned before that I change from "class id" to just "id" but when I tried it, it didn't work.  However, moving the tag inside the body tag along with the id change did the trick.  Thanks for the assist!